# Api node js y typescript a produccion

Tags: nodejs, typescript

Hola espero me puedan ayudar con esta duda, cree un api con Nodejs y Typescript y lo compile y los archivos se guardaron en la carpeta dist la pregunta es para pasarlo a producción en nginx en Windows, solo tengo que pasar la carpeta compilada dist o tengo que pasarme todo el proyecto al servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar tu API de Node.js y TypeScript a producción en un servidor con NGINX en Windows, solo necesitas copiar la carpeta "dist" y sus contenidos al servidor. La carpeta "dist" contiene los archivos compilados y es lo único que necesitas para ejecutar tu API en producción. No es necesario copiar todo el proyecto completo al servidor.

Sin embargo, es posible que también quieras incluir otros elementos en tu servidor, como un archivo de configuración de NGINX, un archivo de inicio de PM2 (si estás utilizando PM2 como tu gestor de procesos) y cualquier otro archivo o dependencia necesaria para la ejecución de tu API.

Es importante también asegurarte de tener todas las dependencias necesarias instaladas en el servidor y de tener una forma de iniciar y detener tu API de manera adecuada. Puedes utilizar herramientas como PM2 para facilitar el proceso de inicio y detención de tu API.

En resumen, para pasar tu API a producción en un servidor con NGINX en Windows, solo necesitas copiar la carpeta "dist" y cualquier otro archivo o dependencia necesaria para la ejecución de tu API al servidor.